# Linear regression for time series with Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, time-series, linear-regression

I am a big fan of Gnuplot and I used it all along my studies for various projects.

Lately I wanted to use Gnuplot to chart some time series like weight loss, exercising results, gas consumptions etc.

Therefore I scale the x-axis like

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d.%m %Y"
set format x "%d.%m"
```

Now I want to use the fit-function to give me a linear fit. My problem is, that I cannot get that to work if the x-axis is time-related.

Comment: [R](http://www.r-project.org/) is probably a better tool for this kind of problem.
It is one of most popular languages for data analysis. Plotting is as simple (or simpler) as in gnu plot.

Answer (score 3):

Then change the date to a number, for example a number of days starting from the first date, make the fit, and then convert the numbers back again into dates.
That way you'll have "regular" x and y data set.

Comment: +1 for being the only person to attempt to answer the question, which was "how do I do this in gnuplot".